# I want to paste formatted text from MS Word by keeping the formation same in my tinyMCE editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, wysiwyg, paste

I am using tinyMCE wysiwyg editor. I want to paste formatted text from MS Word by keeping the formation same in my editor.

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea#main_content",
    menubar:false,
    height: 344,
    min_height:344,
    font_size: 20,
    resize: false,
    browser_spellcheck : true,
    contextmenu: false,
    'plugins': [
        "link",
        "searchreplace",
        "paste"
    ],
    paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste : true,
    paste_word_valid_elements: "b,strong,i,em,h1,h2,u,p,ol,ul,li,a[href]",
    paste_remove_styles: false,
    paste_retain_style_properties: "all",
    paste_preprocess : function(pl, o) {
        o.content = strip_tags( o.content,'<b><u><i><p><br><a><ul><ol><li><strong><em><span><h1><h2><h3>');
    },
    paste_postprocess : function(pl, o) {
        o.node.innerHTML = o.node.innerHTML;
    },
    toolbar: "undo redo | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link pasteword",
    setup : function(ed) {
      ed.on('keyup', function(e) {
           window.clearTimeout(keyupTimer);
           keyupTimer = setTimeout(function(){
                updateTxtarea();
                seo_validate(1);
                instant_word_count();
           },2000);
      });
      ed.on('focus', function(e) {
            if($('.skin-toolbox-toggle').hasClass('toolbox-open')){
                $('.skin-toolbox-toggle').trigger('click');
            }
      });
   }
});
```

I am using the code above. Bold, italics, underlined, ul, li, hyperlink are working, these are ok but I need font-size, text-align, color also to remain same in my tinyMCE editor same as in MS word.

I have googled a lot but exact solution not found. Please help me....

Answer (score 0):

```
paste_retain_style_properties: "all"
```

should be what you looking for, but as this does not work, maybe try to replace `all` with `color font-size…`

Or set `paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste` to `false`, as the documentation does not really specify what this actually does

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "span" to the list of paste.word.valid.elements

I see that being used to contain color, size, and font info.